# How can I see if my Xamarin.Forms app is working or/and runnable on Android 6 (or higher) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm working on an application and I am wondering what version of Android I can run my app on.

### Question

Is there any way to see that in Visual Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your [Minimum Android Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows#minimum) to see the oldest Android version that you want your app to support. This can be done by right click on Android project, then Properties, then Android Manifest:

[image]

To test it, you can use [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows). You can create a virtual device with desired Android version as OS:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to Android Project
2. Go Inside Properties folder
3. Open AndroidManifest.xml file
4. You will see Android Target Version

The Target Android version is the API level of the Android device where the app expects to run.

If your target version is selected to android 6 then it means your app can be run up to android 6 or. Similarly, if you set it to android 9 then your application can run up to android 9 OS